# Why add control variables in the second stage of an IV regression?

Tags: instrumental-variables, endogeneity, controlling-for-a-variable

I am reading an article on the effect of income on energy choice (e.g., choice between traditional sources such as charcoal and modern ones such as electricity).

The authors instrument income with rainfall, the intuition behind which I understand (i.e., b/c of both reverse causality and OVB issues).

What I don't understand is why they include controls (wealth, education, household age, etc) in the second stage of the regression (ie, energychoice = instrumented income + controls).

If rainfall is exogeneous (which it would seem for me to be), shouldn't controlling for additional variables in the second stage be unnecessary ?

Many thanks !

Edit : you can find the article here -> https://sun-connect.org/wpcont/uploads/s41598-023-29285-6.pdf

Comment: Perhaps you can share info on the actual article. I think most people won't really be able to guess the intentions of authors if they don't have a source to work with.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand : thanks ! I have just edited it.

Comment: https://theeffectbook.net/ch-InstrumentalVariables.html is, in my opinion, helpful in (not only) this regard